# Unauthorized even though I am authorized laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my Profilepolicy, I have method viewAny

```
public function viewAny(User $user, Profile $profile){
        return $user->id === $profile->user_id;
    }
```

In my profile controller I have the gate above the view:

```
Gate::authorize('viewAny', $profile);
```

Now when I try to click my profile, it returns action is unauthorized.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#authorizing-resource-controllers)? You should use `viewAny` only for the index view, meaning if the user can view **any** profile, looking at your code you should use `view` to determine if the user has access to the given (singular) profile.

Comment: I have read the documentation. In my profile views, the index is the main page of the profile. return view ('profile.index',

Comment: I tried changing it to view, but it didn't work either